# Is it possible to have multiple opacities in a window?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm thinking of having something like this:

```
<Grid> <-- opacity is .5
    <Grid></Grid> <-- opacity is .9 (of total opacity, not relative to parent)
    <Grid></Grid> <-- opacity is .9
    <Grid></Grid> <-- opacity is .9
</Grid>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage Grid(s) in another Grid?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="3"><Grid> <-- opacity is .5 
    <Grid Grid.Column="0"></Grid>    <-- opacity is .9
    <Grid Grid.Column="1"></Grid>    <-- opacity is .9 
    <Grid Grid.Column="2"></Grid>    <-- opacity is .9 
</Grid>
```